Druid Wild Shape + Increased Ability Score from Feats
If a Feat grants an ability score increase as part of its benefits, does that ability score increase get applied to the new ability scores when a druid wild shapes?
Wild shape says:

Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast, but
you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and
Charisma scores.

This means the character's Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution gets replaced by the new form.  However, Wild Shape also says:

You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other
source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing
so.

Many feats include an ability score increase by 1 point as part of their benefits.  Examples include Athlete, Durable, Resilient, etc.
Does the new form retain the +1 bonus to Strength/Dexterity/Constitution granted by a Feat?

Hello there! I closed this since it has already asked before, in the linked post.

Thanks.  So a Feat is treated the same as an ASI for the purpose of this question and its resolution?

In my opinion yes, since the effect are actually the same: if you believe that there are differences between the two cases, then you can explain them in the question and ask for reopening it.
